# covariant derivative of a function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $f$ be a smooth function such on a compact kahler manifold $(M, w)$, and the component of $w$ is denoted by $g_{ij}$, assume there is a constant $s$ such that $sf = -g^{ij}\sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{i}f$, want to prove the following:

$s \nabla_j f   = -\nabla_j \nabla_p \nabla_{\bar p} f$ suppresing the mertic,

where $\nabla \nabla \nabla$ is intepreted as in [the first answer in here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510254/commutation-of-covariant-derivative-of-functions)

Thoughts: the left hand side is simply $\partial_j sf = \partial_j-g^{ik}\sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{k}f = - \partial_j g^{ik} \sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{k}f -\partial_j\sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{k}f g^{ik}$

How do you realize that $- \partial_j g^{ik} \sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{k}f -\partial_j\sqrt{-1}\partial_{j}\bar\partial_{k}f g^{ik} = -\nabla_j \nabla_p \nabla_{\bar p} f$ immediately?

When doing calculations, can you just naively replace partial derivative by covariant derivative?

Comment: Your question is basically why $g^{ij} \sqrt{-1} \partial_j \bar{\partial}_i f = \nabla_p \nabla_{\bar{p}} f$, no?

Comment: No. Are you trying to suggest that $\nabla_j \nabla_p \nabla_p f = \nabla_j( \nabla_p \nabla_p f )$? According to the thread I posted, it should be interpreted as $\nabla \nabla \nabla f (\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j},  \frac{\bar \partial}{\partial z_p}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j})$.

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting exactly that. $\nabla_p \nabla_{\bar{p}} f$ has the implicit summation over $p$ and _is a scalar_.

Comment: If you think of $\nabla_j \nabla_p \nabla_{\bar{p}} f$ as you wrote, as a component of a rank three object, it makes no sense to even think that can be equal to the component of a rank one object ($s \nabla_j f$)...

Comment: Well originally it is something like $\int_{M}s \nabla_j f \nabla_{\bar j} f w_{f}^n = \int _{M} \nabla_j \nabla_p \nabla_{\bar p} f \nabla_{\bar j} f w_{f}^n$, maybe I intepreted it wrong?

Comment: I am so confused as to how do you carry out this kind of computation using covariant derivatives for a function.

Comment: Fundamentally: you need to look up how index summation convention works in the book/paper you are reading. Also, note that on a Kahler manifold, for **scalar functions** you have the mixed derivatives $\nabla_i \nabla_{\bar{j}} f = \partial_i \partial_{\bar{j}} f$ because Kahler requires the mixed index Christoffel symbols to vanish. You may want to look at a text that does Kahler manifolds in local coordinates (an example being Aubin's "Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry", but there are certainly others.)

Comment: I see.  Do you maybe want to write up something so that I can accept as an answer?